# NavigationService error in WP8 app

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

I'm trying to implement simple code, that allows user to go to another app-page with transferring parameter/variable "Totall" to next page:

```
 Private Sub HyperlinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/Mainpage.xaml?totall=" & Totall, UriKind.Relative))

        Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage))
    End Sub
```

But I get an error "NavigationService is not declared". Why is happening?
This is WP8.1 app on Framework 4.5
This is not a Silverlight app.
Yes, I have declared Imports Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationService` is not available in WinRT. To pass parameters while navigating, you can use the second line in your method and just add the parameter:

```
Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage), Totall)
```

To retrieve this parameter on the target page, override the `OnNavigatedTo` method like in the following example:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As NavigationEventArgs)
    total1 = e.Parameter as Integer
End Sub
```

If you want to use `NavigationService`, you'd need to switch to a Windows Phone Silverlight app...